# Using fileStorage in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to save my cameramatrix into a  **yml** file  using cv::FileStorage , this work fine :

```
cv::FileStorage  fs("calibration_result.yml",cv::FileStorage::WRITE);

..............

this->fs << "the camera matrix is "<<this->cameraMatrix;
```

here is what I get :

```
the camera matrix is : !!opencv-matrix  /* why do I get this 
   rows: 
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 6.9722486929603847e+003, 0., 6.3950000000000000e+002, 0.,
       7.0010247500898549e+003, 5.1150000000000000e+002, 0., 0., 1. ]
```

what I want to get is :

```
the camera matrix is :
[ 6.9722486929603847e+003, 0., 6.3950000000000000e+002, 0.,
           7.0010247500898549e+003, 5.1150000000000000e+002, 0., 0., 1. ]
```

I already tried to use `cameraMatrix.data` it didn't help!

any idea how can I do this!

thanks in advance !

Comment: You get what you need with little bit more information. Why is that a problem? Can you explain your problem more detailed?

Comment: who said that's a problem ? I didn't ? I just want to know if it possible to do it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cameraMatrix should have type `cv::Mat`. `cv::Mat` is saved this way as can be seen in `modules/core/src/persistence.cpp` (see `icvWriteMat`)
OpenCV won't be able to understand `cv::Mat` size without that additional data (is this `[...]` 3x3 or 1x9 matrix?) and writting is usually used to read written later. You could write what you want using some raw writting techniques (and won't able to read it using opencv) or make your own serializable `matrix3x3` or `cameraMatrix` type.